# Boolean Algebra Minimization

Tags: boolean-algebra

Prove that

$\bar{A}B + AC + BC = \bar{A}B + AC$

with the help of boolean algebraic manipulations. I have no clue from where to start, how should  I tackle these type of questions?

Or

$$
\left(\neg A \wedge B\right)\vee \left(A \wedge C\right)\vee\left(B \wedge C\right) = \left(\neg A \wedge B\right)\vee \left(A \wedge C\right)$$

Comment: You haven't written anything in any kind of boolean algebra that I understand.  It looks more like set algebra, where $\bar{A}$ means the complement of the set $A$ (i.e. every value that is _not_ in the set $A$).  I also don't know how to interpret juxtaposition, i.e. $\bar{A}B$, and I don't know how to interpret addition, i.e. $+$.  Does juxtaposition mean an intersection?  And addition ($+$) mean union? Or what?

Comment: A and B are boolean variables, the $\bar A$ denotes NOT A, AB denotes A AND B and A+B denotes A OR B

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**  Since you want to get rid of the term $BC$, maybe it makes sense to do something to it : $$\begin{align}\bar{A}B + AC + BC &= \bar{A}B + AC + (A+\bar{A})BC\\&=\bar{A}B + AC + ABC+\bar{A}BC\end{align} $$

Group first and last terms
Group middle two terms

Comment: thanks! could you explain the motivation for this problem?

Comment: I think simplification is the main motivation for most boolean algebra problems. I'm not gonna lie here, its not that obvious why/how one comes up with anding $A+\bar{A}$ to $BC$; there might be other ways to approach this problem but since we know that we need to kick out $BC$, anding A+A' looks like a good start :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to start from the obvious, if $A$ is false, then clearly either $B$ or $B$ *and* $C$ must be true.  Right away, this means that when $A$ is false, $B$ *cannot* be false.  So this suggests $\neg A \wedge B$.  Now, if $A$ is true then either $C$ is true *or* $C$ *and* $B$ is true--either way $C$ is true, therefore it's clear that this is equivalent to $(A \wedge B)\vee (\neg A \wedge C)$.